# Find $P(X\geq 0)$ when $X$ is normal with mean $-\frac{1}{2}\delta^2$ and variance $\delta^2$

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution

Let $X\sim N(-\frac{1}{2}\delta^2.\delta^2)$
What is $P(X\geq 0)$.

$$P(X\geq 0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\delta^2\pi}}\int^\infty_0\exp\{\frac{-(X+\frac{1}{2}\delta^2)^2}{2\delta^2}\}dx$$

I use the substitution $Y=(X+1/2\delta^2)/\delta\Rightarrow dx=dy$

We have:

$$P(X\geq 0)={\sqrt{2\delta^2\pi}}\int^\infty_{1/2\delta}\exp\{-Y^2/2\}dy$$

$$=\frac{1}{\delta}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}}\int^\infty_{1/2\delta}\exp\{-Y^2/2\}dy$$

$$=\frac{1}{\delta}\Phi(-1/2\delta)$$

> But my notes say it should be $\Phi(-1/2\delta)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that
$$y=\frac{x+\frac{1}{2}\delta^2}{\delta}\implies \mathrm d x=\delta \cdot \mathrm d y$$

Comment: Thanks, I was going in circles over and over

Comment: Let us try to avoid mixing random variables (uppercase) and arguments of integrals (lowercase).

Comment: @Did: For a 216K you could have edited much better :-D

Comment: @Surb You mean, rewrite entirely the answer? I rarely do.

Comment: @Did: I can understand :-) (for the first time I did it...) Good evening :-)

Comment: @Surb If the edit you just did is the one you were alluding to in your comment to me then I am sorry but I am not convinced by its necessity.

Comment: @Did:of course it's not, what I did is brags only :-D (your edit was perfect :-))